# Coinciding circle fills on Folium

Tags: python, folium

I am trying to combine two circles to get something like this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54913931/add-overlapping-circles-to-leaflet-map-with-homogeneous-transparency).
[image]

However, I couldn't convert the solution in this post to Python. I need these circles to behave almost like one, but cannot find the solution.

[image]

```
    folium.Circle(
        [lat, lon],
        radius=req_distance(reduction, source_R) * 2,
        popup="Limit d2B",
        tooltip="limit 22",
        fill=True,
        opacity=0.1,
        fill_opacity=0.25,
        fill_color="yellow",
        color="green",
    ).add_to(map)
    folium.Circle(
        [lat + 0.002, lon],
        radius=req_distance(reduction, source_R) * 2,
        popup="Limit d2B",
        tooltip="limit 22",
        fill=True,
        opacity=0.1,
        fill_opacity=0.25,
        fill_color="yellow",
        color="green",
    ).add_to(map)
```

Comment: Heyo @user3243944. Nice question. Two suggestions to make it easier to answer your question: 1. it's nice if you can ask a very straight forward question ending with a question mark instead of stating the problem; 2. give a full Python code example (including definition of variables lat, lon, reduction, source_R and imports).

Comment: Heyo @user3243944. Nice question. Two suggestions to make it easier to answer your question: 1. it's nice if you can ask a very straight forward question ending with a question mark instead of stating the problem; 2. give a full Python code example (including definition of variables lat, lon, reduction, source_R and imports).